# creating TypeScript definitions for existing jslibraries nameclash issues

Tags: ember.js, typescript

I have started making TypeScript definitions for the Ember.js framework. I have currently set it up structured like this:

```
declare module Ember {
   interface Classname {
     someProperty: type;
   }
 declare var Classname: Classname;
}
```

In order to access these interfaces I declare a variable. However in my library there is a classname called Object, this causes a nameclash with the Object from the global scope.

How do I surpass this nameclash? And am I using the right practise for creating definitions for an existing library?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to grab the EmberJS definition file from GitHub:

https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/ember/ember-1.0.d.ts

This not only solves your problem as it has the Ember definition, but you can also see how they achieved it in spite of name clashes:

```
declare module Ember {

    export class Object extends CoreObject {
        //...
```

This makes Object a child of Ember, rather than of window:

```
Ember.Object
```

Rather than

```
window.Object
// or the shorthand
Object // which is window.Object
```

Comment: The definitions on that project are not yet finished (I was planning on contributing to them actually). I wonder why use classes when you are not implementing any logic. Ember makes no use of the new keyword when instantiating objects so there is no need to define a constructor or any of the (class) features of TypeScript I can think of. But I guess that does solve my nameclash problem. However I will try to make it work with just interfaces and post back results.

Comment: You should be able to use the same concept with interfaces by exporting them from an Ember module - so the interface would be Ember.Interface

Comment: Since .d.ts files do not generate any code, classes inside them behave very similarly to an interface. Also, you are welcome to improve the Ember definitions and do a pull request.